# MFC Clistcontrol hover effect

Tags: mfc

I'm confused about what is the best way to implement a hover effect for `ClistCtrl`.

What I mean is when I mouse over a row of report view, the background changes, and the background color changes back after mouse leaves the view.

Can anybody give me some examples or tips?

p.s. it's for calling out the hover effect when applying owner draw function!?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in OnInitDialog when I use a CListCtrl :

```
m_list.SetExtendedStyle (LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
SetWindowTheme(m_list.m_hWnd, L"Explorer", NULL) ;
m_list.SetExtendedStyle(list.GetExtendedStyle() | LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER);
```

That way the list control is displayed with a more modern style on Vista, W7 and W8 and you automatically get the behaviour you want. BTW list controls in Explorer also behave like this.

But you won't get this behaviour on Windows XP.

Comment: thanks Michael, i did what you said but nothing happen. is there any conflict between the method that u provide and drawitem or mouse move function?

Comment: then anyone gets the idea how to call out the hover effect when applying owner draw function!?